# embedded QPid broker - Web Management Console not loading

Tags: java, amqp, qpid

The management console is not able to run when the broker is started with the below artifact for QPid. Am I missing a dependency or configuration in the below setup?

pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.qpid</groupId>
        <artifactId>qpid-broker</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Broker broker = new Broker();
    broker.startup();
}
```

There are no errors on startup.

Chrome console:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you configuring the class path for your Main class's execution?

The problem is that Java Broker expects the Dojo .zip (dojo-1.10.3-distribution.zip) file to be present in the JVMs class path.  The Broker locates the Dojo's resources on the class path and arranges for the embedded Jetty to stream them.

Comment: Since the broker was added as a maven dependency it was the wrong expectation that it's pom.xml had this sorted out. Manually adding dojo to my project and unwrapping dojo files in the target war resolved the issue